# Java drawImage() not drawing

Tags: java, swing

Within my program, I have the following code:

```
package io.github.AdmiralSbs.DiceWars;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HexDisplay extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int SIZE = 200;
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private Hex[][] hex;
    private BufferedImage myImage;
    private Graphics drawer;

    public HexDisplay(File f) throws IOException {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(f);
        int[] temp = commaSplit(key.nextLine());
        height = temp[0];
        width = temp[1];
        hex = new Hex[width][height];
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
            for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
                //temp = commaSplit(key.nextLine());
                if (h % 2 == 0)
                    hex[w][h] = new Hex((int) (SIZE * (w + 0.5)),
                            (int) (SIZE * (h + 0.5)), SIZE);
                else
                    hex[w][h] = new Hex((int) (SIZE * (w + 1.5)),
                            (int) (SIZE * (h + 0.5)), SIZE);
                System.out.println(hex[w][h].getX() + " " + hex[w][h].getY());
            }
        }
        key.close();
        starting();
        ImageIO.write(myImage, "jpg", new File("outPic.jpg"));
    }

    public void starting() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        myImage = new BufferedImage(400, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        drawer = myImage.getGraphics();
        drawer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        drawer.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
        drawStuff(drawer);
        repaint();
    }

    public int[] commaSplit(String s) {
        String[] str = s.split(",");
        int[] ret = new int[str.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            ret[i] = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, this);
        System.out.println("Painted");
    }

    public void drawStuff(Graphics g) {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
            for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
                hex[w][h].draw(g);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Drew");
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        paintComponents(g);
    }
}
```

What I would expect to happen is for the frame that contains this JPanel to display the image, but it does not.  All System.out.println() methods are called as expected, and I am able to save the image as a .jpg file.  However, the image is not displayed in the GUI.  What can be done?

Comment: For custom painting, consider calling `paintComponent` instead of `paintComponents` .

Comment: Where is your `starting()` called from?

Comment: starting() is called from the constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
//                        v
public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
```

It should be `paintComponent`.

And should contain a call to super method:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

as the first line in the method

Comment: OP should also use the @Override annotation to prevent this in the future.

Comment: @SteveSmith My answer originally said that as well but Berger pointed out to me that [`paintComponents`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#paintComponents-java.awt.Graphics-) is actually a method which exists. (I'd never noticed it before either. I guess it must be an older AWT method, since Swing components normally use `paintChildren` for that purpose.)

Comment: The computer I'm on doesn't allow me to use annotations, kinda sucks

Comment: @JasonWatkins what on earth do you mean? Are you using Java 1.4? Or does your keyboard lack an `@` key?

Comment: Pretty sure it's 1.4